# ¿Cómo alternar el color de las filas de un vaadin-grid con un subgrid como detalle

Tags: polymer, vaadin

Tengo un vaadin-grid que tiene otro vaadin-grid como su detalle

Se necesita alternar los colores de las filas, impares beige y pares blanco, las filas impares propagan su color al detella(excelente), pero las filas pares no propagan su color al detalle, ocurre algo extraño, el detalle esta alternando su color

```
<style is="custom-style">
    vaadin-grid#mainGrid {
        --vaadin-grid-body-row-odd-cell: {
            background-color: beige;
        };
    }
</style>

<template is="dom-bind">
    <iron-ajax url="https://randomuser.me/api?results=5" last-response="{{response}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    <iron-ajax url="https://randomuser.me/api?results=3" last-response="{{response2}}" auto></iron-ajax>
    <vaadin-grid items="{{response.results}}" style="height: auto;" id="mainGrid">
        <template class="row-details">
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <vaadin-grid items="{{response2.results}}" id="detailGrid" style="height: 101px;" >
                <vaadin-grid-column width="100px" flex-grow="1" >
                    <template>***[[item.name.first]]</template>
                </vaadin-grid-column>
            </vaadin-grid>
        </template>
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Name</template>
            <template>[[item.name.first]] [[item.name.last]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">expand</template>
            <template>
                <paper-checkbox aria-label$="Show Details " checked="{{expanded}}">Show Details</paper-checkbox>
            </template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>
    </vaadin-grid>
</template>
```

ejemplo: https://jsbin.com/zexinam/edit?html,output
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]